# Span gets out from external div only after the end of the animation

Tags: jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

I did the animation effect using jQuery:

http://jsfiddle.net/rxCDU/

**UPD**: This works only in Chrome!

This animation effect works properly except that the green SPAN gets out from external red DIV **only after the end of the animation**. Why? I want the green SPAN was over the red DIV immediately with the beginning of the animation. I'm not very strong in CSS. I played with `z-index` and `position` styles but it did not bring the desired result.

*HTML*:

```
<div class="ext_div">
   <div class="int_div"><span>A</span></div>
</div>
```

*CSS*:

```
.ext_div {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-50deg);
}

div.ext_div div {
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -400px;
    padding-left: 80px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    font-size: 350px;
}

div.ext_div div span {
    background-color: green;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;

    -webkit-transform: skewY(50deg);
    -moz-transform: skewY(50deg);
    -o-transform: skewY(50deg);
    -ms-transform: skewY(50deg);
    transform: skewY(50deg);
}
```

*jQuery-CODE*:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     $(".int_div").queue(function () {
        $(this).animate({width: "150", height: "125", right: "+=200", "font-size": "150px" }, 1200)
               .queue(function () {
                    $(this).addClass("myclass");}).dequeue();
     });    

 return false;

});
```

How can I solve my problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery add overflow hidden while animating. Found 2 solutions.

First one is to add overflow visible to the div with an !important (not a good practice).

```
div.ext_div div {
    overflow : visible!important;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -400px;
    padding-left: 80px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    font-size: 350px;
}
```

jsfiddle.net/rxCDU/2

The second one is to use `step` and override the overflow:

```
$(this).animate({width: "150", height: "125", right: "+=200", "font-size": "150px" }, {duration : 1200, step : function(){
         $(this).css('overflow', 'visible')
}})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rxCDU/4/